# IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0, only called once, seems to not be working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 (Express)

I was using a query like this to decide whether to insert or find the record, based on whether an identical record already existed.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Divisions WHERE Title = '$Title')
  BEGIN
    SELECT NEWID = DIVISIONID, CREATED = 'FALSE' FROM Divisions WHERE Title = '$Title'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DIVISIONS(Title)
    VALUES('$Title')
    SELECT CREATED = 'True", NEWID = SCOPE_IDENTIY()
  END
```

The WHERE condition from the EXISTS statement was repeated in the first select, more work, more to maintain, and doing the same scan twice.

---

I thought I could change it to this. **I'm trying to understand WHY this query doesn't work.**

```
SELECT NEWID = DivisionID, CREATED = 'False'
 FROM Divisions D2
   WHERE Title = '$Title'

  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Divisions (Title)
      VALUES('$Title')
      SELECT NEWID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(), CREATED = 'TRUE'
    END
```

This query always returns no rows if there's no match.

The expected behavior is for a match is (this is happening properly)

1. Run the query, find the record. SET CREATED to FALSE and NEWID to the matching DIVISIONID.
2. @@ROWCOUNT = 1, so skip the insert.

The expected behavior otherwise is

1. Run the query, find no matching record.
2. @@ROWCOUNT = 0? So perform the INSERT indie the IF
3. Set NEWID to SCOPE_IDENTITY(), and CREATED to TRUE, return these.

---

But this similar code works.

```
DECLARE @OBJECTID INT = 0
SELECT @OBJECTID = DivisionID
 FROM Divisions D2
   WHERE Title = '$Title'

  IF (ISNULL(@OBJECTID,0) = 0)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Divisions (Title)
      VALUES('$Title')
      SELECT NEWID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(), CREATED = 'TRUE'
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      SELECT NEWID = @OBJECTID, CREATED = 'FALSE'
    END
```

---

Aside from simplifying the INSERT Statement and the WHERE conditions, these are complete queries. There are no triggers or Foreign Indexes on the table.

Comment: Your new code will return two result sets when there is no matching row. The first one with no rows and a second result set with the values. Your "similar" code is the best option in my opinion.

Comment: I'm curious; what are `NEWID` and `CREATED`? They aren't variables/parameters since they don't have the @ symbol prefix.

Comment: @DeanOC those are the column names in the result set. Probably not exactly what the OP had in mine but who knows?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, but it is what I had in mind. That way I can return it to my code and make a decision on the dialog shown to the user.

Comment: So use your last query and it will all be returned in a single result set.